# Temporary values in tokio::select! macro

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, rust-tokio, temporary

I think I have some understanding of temporaries, their lifetimes and references to them. But I don't understand what's wrong in the following situation:

```
use std::io;

use tokio::signal::unix::{self, SignalKind};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    tokio::select! {
        _ = unix::signal(SignalKind::interrupt())?.recv() => (),
        _ = unix::signal(SignalKind::terminate())?.recv() => (),
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

As the compiler tells us, the temporaries are freed at the end of the `select!` macro in line 10. The temporaries are borrowed only by the receive methods within the `select!` macro. After the `select!` macro, we immediately return from the function. There are no further borrows. What is wrong in this situation? And what does the message "borrow later captured here by closure" mean?

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> routing_server/src/main.rs:9:13
   |
7  | /     tokio::select! {
8  | |         _ = unix::signal(SignalKind::interrupt())?.recv() => (),
9  | |         _ = unix::signal(SignalKind::terminate())?.recv() => (),
   | |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
10 | |     }
   | |     -
   | |     |
   | |_____temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |       borrow later captured here by closure
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I can fix the situation by introducing local variables for the temporaries. The question is more about what's the problem rather than how to fix it. I think I haven't fully understood Rust's concepts yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the code generated by using `cargo expand`. Here you see that the arm of the macro is captured in a `future`.

I have added a minimal example showing a similar situation in code, without the usage of the macro. In this example `await` is called on the `future`, but the compiler error message is the same.

`Signal` cannot be dropped because a `future` still has a reference pointing to it.

**Example**

```
    use std::error::Error;
    
    struct Signal {}
    
    impl Signal {
        async fn recv(&mut self) -> () {
            ()
        }
    }
    
    #[tokio::main]
    async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>  {
        // tokio::select! {
        //     _ = Signal {}.recv() => (),
        // }
        let future = Signal {}.recv();
        future.await;
        
        Ok(())
    }
```

**Compiler Error**

```
    16 |     let future = Signal {}.recv();
       |                  ^^^^^^^^^       - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
       |                  |
       |                  creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
    17 |     future.await;
       |     ------ borrow later used here
```